# How to invoke an "external" action based on a javascript call

Tags: go, webview, webkitgtk

on a golang/webview application, I need to be able to call an external application when a certain javascript call is rendered on the web application.
I have been using https://github.com/zserge/webview and window.external.invoke for a while now, but it seems this call is deprecated, can you think of an alternative?